# How to check no. of rows returned when using MYSQLI_STMT_PREPARE and MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY?

Tags: php, mysqli

I thought I could use `MYSQLI_STMT_NUM_ROWS` and `MYSQLI_STMT_STORE_RESULT`to check for no. of rows returned. (see commented lines ///1///, ///2///, ///3///)

But it doesn't seem to in the context below.

This codes does work (without the commented lines), but I am trying to add an extra check, to confirm that no more than 1 record is returned. (even though this should always be the case, as the email field in the table is unique, but it doesn't hurt to do the check anyway).

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

This is the error I get below (line 86 if the `WHILE` ... line):

> An error occurred in script 'L:\includes\login_functions.inc.php' on line 86: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

NOTE:

This a stripped down version of the original code.

`$form_email` and `$form_pass` are originated from form input.

Code is procedural, because I like it that way.

```
<?php
// Prepared statement.
$prep_sel = 'SELECT user_id, first_name, user_level, pass FROM users WHERE email=? and active is null';
// Initialise connection.
$stmt_sel = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);
// Check if there are any DB connection problems.
....
// Prepare statement, bind parameters (an integer and a string) and execute the statement
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_sel, $prep_sel)) {
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_sel, 's', $form_email);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_sel);
     ///1///mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_sel);
}

///2///if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_sel) == 1) { // one record found.
     // Get the results.
     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt_sel);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          // Now check if the passwords match.
          if (password_verify($form_pass, $row['pass'])) {
              return array(true, $row);
          } else {
              $errors[] = 'the details you provided does not match our records';
              $errors[] = 'your account has not been activated';
          }
      }
///3///}
/* close statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt_sel);
?>
```

Comment: You said it does work except for commented lines, but it's erroring on `mysqli_fech_array()`?  That would indicate it got a `false` return from `mysqli_stmt_get_result()`.

Comment: If I just uncomment ///1/// I get the error mentioned. ($result = ...) remains unchanged.

Comment: These things occur after the `if(mysqli_stmt_prepare())` block - Did it definitely prepare/bind/execute successfully?

Comment: Yes and yes, I get a valid return and a set of results returned. The error only occurs after adding line ///1/// whilst ///2/// ///3/// are commented out.

Comment: It seems that adding the mysqli_stmt_store_result statement is somehow breaking things and I don't understand why. Is my use of this function incorrect ?

Comment: Test `echo mysqli_error($dbc);`  Do you get a "commands out of sync" error if you call that right after `mysqli_stmt_get_result()`?

Comment: Just tested it as you suggested and yes i get "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69976/discussion-between-user3526609-and-michael-berkowski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`, the MySQL driver will not permit you to operate on a result set until all rows are fetched or the result set is freed and the statement closed.  So a subsequent call to `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` will return `false`, and probably result in an error like

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

which you may check with `echo mysqli_error($dbc);`

Transferring the statement's result set with `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` will give you access to its `num_rows` property, so you actually don't need to use `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`.  Instead just rely on `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` before checking the number of rows returned:

```
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_sel, $prep_sel)) {
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_sel, 's', $form_email);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_sel);

     // Transfer the result set here:
     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt_sel);

     // Then check rows returned on the $result obj
     // using mysqli_num_rows(), not mysqli_stmt_num_rows()
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          // Check your password, etc....
       }
     }
     else {
        // More than 1, do whatever you need to handle this
     }

     // Close it
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt_sel);
}
```

Comment: (It's API weirdness like this that makes me hate MySQLi and prefer PDO)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is the answer to my problem. And you are right this is weird!

Comment: You're welcome. It's sort of because `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` was added late, in PHP 5.3 and the mysqlnd driver. It improves the fetch procedures from what was needed with `bind_result()` but documentation is terrible and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
function authenticateUser($email, $password){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id, first_name, user_level, pass FROM users WHERE email=? and active is null");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    if($res->num_rows > 0){
        $hash = $res->fetch_object()->pass;
        if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
            return true;
        }    
    }
    return false;
}
```

call the function

```
if(authenticateUser($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])){
    //do something
}
else{
    echo "Invalid Email/Password";
}
```