# Retrieve results from database using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, associative-array

I've just started using PHP prepared statements and thought I was starting to understand them. However, I'm having major problems with the following code which suggests my understanding is not as thorough as I thought it was. I've tried lots of variations but I'm still getting a fatal error.

Basically, I've used prepared statements to insert data into a database. That bit works fine. I then want to retrieve the latest inserted record to display to the user so they can check that everything is OK. It is likely that the database will be updated on a fairly regular basis and new columns may be added to the tables as required. Consequently, I don't want to bind_result() to a prescribed list of variables but, instead, I want to retrieve an associative array that I can step through with a loop. A simplified version of the code (without error checking) is given below:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");

// Insert record into database using prepared statement...
// Works fine.

// Retrieve recently installed data...
$EnteredDataStmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM correspondence where id = ?")
$EnteredDataStmt->bind_param('i', $LatestInsertID)

// Get ID number of latest inserted data...
$LatestInsertID = $db->insert_id;

$EnteredDataStmt->execute()

// I want to check that only 1 result is returned...
$EnteredDataStmt->store_result()
$NumResults = $EnteredDataStmt->num_rows;

if($NumResults == 1)
{
    $EnteredDataResult = $EnteredDataStmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $EnteredDataResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))  // <- Error indicates problem at this line
    {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        {
            print "<p>$key: $value</p>";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}

$EnteredDataStmt->close();
unset($EnteredDataResult);
$db->close()
?>
```

When I try to run the above php script, I get a fatal error as follows:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object...
```

The use of get_result() followed by fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) on the result is suggested on several sites but it doesn't seem to work for me. Have I subtly changed the context without realising it? Any suggestions of where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$EnteredDataResult` is not an object, because `$enteredDataStmt->get_result()` returned `false`. You should check `echo $db->error;` to find out what error MySQLi is holding onto there.

Comment: In fact, calling `get_result()` after `store_result()` sounded familiar to me so I looked back and found [this answer from a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258723/how-to-check-no-of-rows-returned-when-using-mysqli-stmt-prepare-and-mysqli-fetc/28258887#28258887)

Comment: Based on what I found in that answer, I think you can get away with using `$EnteredDataResult = $EnteredDataStmt->get_result()` and then check `$EnteredDataResult->num_rows` and fetch from `$EnteredDataResult->fetch_array()`

Comment: Thanks very much for the rapid response! The error message after get_result() is: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. I'll look into all the suggestions you made.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if you need help with your specific implementation, and I can put in a fuller answer. Otherwise this could be marked as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: That seems to have sorted the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be in this order.

```
// Get ID number of latest inserted data...
$LatestInsertID = $db->insert_id;

// Retrieve recently installed data...
$EnteredDataStmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM correspondence where id = ?")
$EnteredDataStmt->bind_param('i', $LatestInsertID)
```

Otherwise `$LatestInsertID` doesn't exist to bind. You also need to implement error handling since your fatal error is caused because the query fails but you aren't seeing it.

```
$EnteredDataStmt->execute();
if (!$EnteredDataStmt) {
    print $EnteredDataStmt->error;
    exit;
}
```